# How to Show Div Partially and on click show it full

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I want a css option for this 
currently i am using this css classes

```
.a{
   top:-102px;
   height: 140px !important;
}

.b{
   top:0px;
   height: 240px !important;
}
```

but this is opening the div from top to bottom and i want it to open from bottom to top

can Anyone please help its very important
 thanks in advance

Comment: for some reason image is not getting displayed

Comment: How about your JavaScript?

Comment: am i the only one who can't understand this question?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno please just take a look at image , thats the functionality i want , with css classes and i can add them via javascript

Comment: @MSD or if you don't want to use JS there's a way of doing it with just CSS, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to wrap your div in another div
2. Give the parent div `position:relative`
3. Give the child div `position:absolute`
4. Anchor the child div using `bottom:0`

Demo 1 uses minimal JavaScript:

- `classList.toggle()`

Demo 2 uses only CSS:

- `<label>` and `<input type='checkbox'>` needed for "trigger"

## Demo 1 (Plain JavaScript)

```js
var x = document.querySelector('.x');

x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('b');
});
```

```css
.y {
  position: relative;
  height: 240px;
  width: 50px;
  background: brown;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: height .5s ease;
}

.b {
  height: 240px;
  transition: height .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class='y'>
  <div class='x'>Click the Red</div>
</div>
```

### Demo 2 (Pure CSS)

```css
.y {
  position: relative;
  height: 240px;
  width: 50px;
  background: brown;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: height .5s ease;
}

#chx {
  display: none
}

#chx:checked+.y .x {
  height: 240px;
  transition: height .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<input id='chx' type='checkbox'>
<div class='y'>
  <label for='chx'>
  <div class='x'>Click on the Red</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, glad to be of help @MSD

Answer (score 0):

You can put one div inside the main div. And give it `overflow: hidden;`

**HTML**

```
<div class='main_div'>
    <div class='overlay_div'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_div{
    height: 240px;
}

.overlay_div{
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.overlay_div').click(function(){
    $('.overlay_div').css({'overflow': 'visible'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try something like this?

```
.b{
   top:0px;
   height: 240px !important;
   display:hidden;
}
```

and with jquery

```
$('.a').click(function(){
    $('.b').show('fast');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution. I hope this will help you.

```js
$('.a').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('b');
})
```

```css
.a{
   position:absolute;
   top:100px;
   height: 50px !important;
   border:1px solid red;
   transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.b{
   top:0px;
   height: 150px !important;
   border:1px solid red;
   transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle `click` with CSS. you must add JavaScript for this.
I have made a sample code for `hover`

Here it's

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="face">Face</div>
  <div class="back">Back</div>
</div>
```

And styling

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper:hover .face {
  margin-top: -100%;
}

.face, .back {
  height: 100%;
  transition: margin ease 0.2s; 
}

.face {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.back {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Here's the a CodePen for you:
https://codepen.io/AbuMuslim/pen/GvEwYz

You can use JS as following:

```
document
  .querySelector('.wrapper')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
```

And instead of using `hover` selector, we change to `.active`, as following:

```
.wrapper.active .face {
  margin-top: -100%;
}
```

Here's a CodePen for that: https://codepen.io/AbuMuslim/pen/QMgJVw

Comment: i am using javscript to add and remove class , but i dont want the effects on hover